# Unable to Resolve Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll Reference in .NET Standard 2.0 Project After Migrating from .NET Framework 4.8

Tags: vb.net, .net-standard, .net-4.8

I've recently migrated a VB.NET class library from .NET Framework 4.8 to .NET Standard 2.0. Post-migration, I'm encountering a persistent build error related to Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll. Despite not having any direct references to this DLL in my project, the build process seems to require it.
The error occurs during the build with the message: Error BC2017: could not find library 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll'.

Steps Taken:

Restored all packages to their .NET Standard 2.0 equivalents.
Verified successful build of other components.
Imported Microsoft.VisualBasic using NuGet, but the build process still fails to find the DLL.
Manually verified the DLL's presence at C:\Users<myuser>.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualbasic\10.3.0\ref\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll.
Attempted adding a direct reference to the DLL in the .vbproj file.

I've tried cleaning and rebuilding the project, checking for correct framework targeting, and ensuring no discrepancies in platform target (x86/x64/AnyCPU).
SDK and Visual Studio are up-to-date.
I've been troubleshooting this issue for a couple of months without success and haven't found any online resources addressing this specific problem. I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this.

Comment: If you have the 4.8 version of the DLL remove the reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic and see what errors you have.

Comment: I created a .NET Standard 2.0 Class library.  A few parts of Microsoft.VisualBasic are present out of the box.  Much of it is not.

Comment: @dbasnett By removing the reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic, do you mean removing the nuget package from my project?

Comment: In the 4.8 version you need to look at the references and remove it there, under Imported Name Spaces.  You might also try changing from 2.0 to 3.0 or 7.0

Comment: @dbasnett When checking the imported namespaces for my project, Microsoft.VisualBasic is there and checked, but I can't uncheck it (the check box is greyed out) like the rest of the other basic System imports

Comment: It could be you are using old VB keywords like Len() Mid() etc. These aren't native to the language anymore and live in that DLL

Comment: @SSS I thought that was the issue before and I went through and 'dotnetified' all of those old VB keywords to rule out that possibility but it looks like that wasn't the problem.

Comment: As an experiment, are you able to start a new .NET Standard class library project that excludes Microsoft.VisualBasic, and start copying code over? You might be able work out where the dependency is.